# Kony not loading the project. Only Loading screen

Tags: temenos-quantum

While opening the project it show only loading screen. project is not loading and not showing any errors.

[image: SCREEN:-]

Answer (score 0):

Try running in eclipse clean mode.

go to installation directory and run command prompt.

> d:\konyInstall> eclipse.exe -clean

Answer (score 0):

You can check logs at a path that will look something like as below:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Kony Visualizer\vizdata\logs
```

for the exact error